# remove text from left and right and keep string in middle

Tags: linux, string, ubuntu, sed, terminal

is there any way to modify this string in linux

```css
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="185.127.7.58" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="115"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="188.128.124.114" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="46"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="163.191.210.41" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="236"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="97.78.205.11" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="45"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="93.103.218.96" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="112"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="75.106.77.247" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="237"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="5.200.35.35" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="120"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="147.196.146.236" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="55"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="89.21.189.7" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="53"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="78.139.51.5" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="108"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="62.193.141.140" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="107"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="136.227.47.165" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="217"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="109.177.46.82" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="50"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="89.116.124.135" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="110"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="88.245.53.232" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="112"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="101.55.37.147" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="108"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="206.201.204.229" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="218"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="120.24.86.220" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="102"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="120.42.185.100" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="43"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="115.47.49.146" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="102"/></port></ports></host>
```

i need to remove this from left :

```
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="
```

and this part from right :

```
" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="115"/></port></ports></host>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbEwr.png)

and keep just the ip in the middle 
how can i do that with sed command in linux ??

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...) to extract value of attribute addr from node address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/^.*addr="\([^"]*\).*$/\1/' file
```

or

```
echo $line |sed 's/^.*addr="\([^"]*\).*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep to filter out only the four dot separated numeric blocks in the IP address:

```
grep -o -P "([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})"
```

Comment: or `grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can just *grep* the `addr` attribute value directly:

```
grep -Po 'addr="\K[^"]*' file
```

The output:

```
185.127.7.58
188.128.124.114
163.191.210.41
97.78.205.11
93.103.218.96
75.106.77.247
5.200.35.35
147.196.146.236
89.21.189.7
78.139.51.5
62.193.141.140
136.227.47.165
109.177.46.82
89.116.124.135
88.245.53.232
101.55.37.147
206.201.204.229
120.24.86.220
120.42.185.100
115.47.49.146
```

Comment: thanx for ur help man it's working .... i need to know if is there any way to found lines contain this string : portid="445"><state state="open" and keep them and delete the lines that contain this string  : portid="3389"><state state="open" ....

Comment: @evilcode1, show the desired output and I'll give a solution

Comment: <host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="185.127.7.58" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="115"/></port></ports></host>
<host endtime="1495011823"><address addr="188.128.124.114" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="46"/></port></ports></host> ....... this 2 line contain diifrance portid 445 and 3389 ... i need to remove all lines that contain 3389 string and keep lines with 445 string

Comment: @evilcode1, now, update your question with new requirements or create new question